# Disable button until checkbox ticked

Tags: html, checkbox, onchange, checked

Apologies if this has already been asked, i have found it difficult to use the answers I have found to use in my code.

Basically, I have a "receive" button, that when the user clicks, will receive an email. But, I want a tick box checked in order for the button to become clickable. I have a code that kind of works, but when the page first loads, the "Receive" button is already clickable. However, when I click the tick box then unclick it, it disables the button.

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="tick" onchange="document.getElementById('terms').disabled = !this.checked;" />
    <td>
    <p> I agree to the <a href="terms.html" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a></p>
    </td>
</td>
</tr>
<td class="label1"></td>
<td align="right">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn1" name="terms" id="terms">Receive</i></button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `disabled` attribute on button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn1" name="terms" disabled id="terms">Receive</i></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the attribute `disabled` to the button initially

```
 <td>
                                <input type="checkbox"  id="tick" onchange="document.getElementById('terms').disabled = !this.checked;" />
            <td>
            <p> I agree to the <a href="terms.html" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a></p>
            </td>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                            <td class="label1"></td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn1" name="terms" id="terms" disabled>Receive</i></button>
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "disabled" attribute to the button is a better solution.

The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that the button should be disabled.

A disabled button is unusable and un-clickable.

Answer (score 0):

please add attrbute **disabled** to the button

I agree to the Terms & Conditions

Receive

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answers:
In simple HTML just Add "disabled" Attribute to button.

With jQuery :

```
    $('#terms').attr('disabled',true);
```

With Css